# C++ Boost.Asio object lifetimes

Tags: c++, boost-asio

```
asio::io_service ioService;
asio::ip::tcp::socket* socket = new asio::ip::tcp::socket(ioService);
socket->async_connect(endpoint, handler);
delete socket;
```

Socket's destructor should close the socket. But can the asynchronous backend handle this? Will it cancel the asynchronous operation and calling the handler? Probably not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the socket is destroyed, it [invokes destroy](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_io_object/_basic_io_object.html) on its service.  When a SocketService's [`destroy()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/SocketService.html) function is invoked, it cancels asynchronous operations by calling a non-throwing `close()`.  Handlers for cancelled operations will be posted for invocation within `io_service` with a `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted` error.

---

Here is a complete example demonstrating the documented behavior:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

void handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
  std::cout << "handle_connect: " << error.message() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  namespace ip = boost::asio::ip;
  using ip::tcp;

  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  // Create socket with a scoped life.
  {
    tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    socket.async_connect(
        tcp::endpoint(ip::address::from_string("1.2.3.4"), 12345),
        &handle_connect);
  }
  io_service.run();
}
```

And its output:

```
handle_connect: Operation canceled
```

Comment: Just to clatify this a bit more. Is it correct that the socket's destructor is allowed to return before the handler has been called? So the handler must remain intact still.

Comment: @NFRCR Yes.  The lifetime of the handler is not coupled to the lifetime of the socket, and the operation will make copies of the handler as necessary.  If the handler is bound to a non-static member function, then it is the application's responsibility to guarantee the instance on which it is bound has a lifetime to be at least as long as that of the handler.  The `enable_shared_from_this` idiom used in the [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3.html#boost_asio.tutorial.tutdaytime3.the_tcp_connection_class) is one way to meet this guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you create the socket using `new`? It won't definitely do normal process.
If you really want to create the `socket` using new, you have to close and delete at the end of your program.

Here is a sample, just.

```
io_service service_;

ip::tcp::socket sock(service_);
sock.async_connect(ep, connect_handler);

deadline_timer t(service_, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
t.async_wait(timeout_handler);

service_.run();
```

Comment: I'm not really using it that way. I'm writing thread safe wrappers around Asio. The documentation lacks information about guarantees and undefined behavior so I'm just trying to explore how it all is behind the scenes.

Comment: @NFRCR OK, I didn't know your hidden intent. Thanks for your comment.